# PS4 preorder automatically cancelled but is a pending payment

Tags: ps4, psn

I preordered Destiny - Rise of Iron yesterday and after that deleted my PayPal information because the PS4 was remembering the password. That then cancelled the preorder but my PayPal account says that the transaction is pending. If I leave it alone, will I still get the preorder? Can I log back in to the PayPal account and the transaction will continue as normal?

Comment: You should contact Sony support for this matter. This is not an issue we will necessarily be able to provide the right kind of answers for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because payment issues of this specific nature are better for official support channels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you preordered this through the PSN and the payment went through at checkout, I do *not* believe that this charge will be cancelled. You should still get the preorder if you received no errors from the PSN. Logging out of PayPal on the PS4 should not void a payment you finalized.

PayPal takes longer than other methods to finish processing, but the payment should be complete within a day or two.